# How to assign an input to an existing list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, input, variable-assignment

I have lists of subjects (english, math and so on) with the names of students in each one, and my objective is to give the program the names of two subjects, and then receive two new lists with the names of students that only appear in the one subject, and names of students that only appear in the other subject.

Some students are in several classes, you see. My problem is that python treats my input variable class1 and class2 as strings, and doesn't assign them to the existing list in the program, even though I'm assigning them to the names of the lists.

```
english=['eve','beatrice','tim','tom']
math=['tim','tom','mary','fiona']
spanish = ['tim','mary','jürgen','mike']
geography = ['farquard','fiona','shrek','donkey']

class1,class2 = input('what classes do you want to work with? ').split(',')

class1_clean = []
for name in class1:
    if name in class2:
        continue
    class1_clean.append(name)
print(class1_clean)

class2_clean = []
for name in class2:
    if name in class1:
        continue
    class2_clean.append(name)
print(class2_clean)
```

Comment: You would use dictionaries for this.

Comment: What do you mean by "My problem is that python treats my input variable class1 and class2 as strings, and doesn't assign them to the existing list in the program"? You want so if they enter "geography", it adds to the `geography` list?

Comment: No, I want the user to enter the name of two subjects (english,math for example) and then the program to generate a list of names that only appear in the list called ' English ' and a list of names that only appear in the list 'math'. Some of the names are in both lists, but I want them clean, so to speak.

Comment: Python is treating `class1` and `class2` as strings because they are indeed user input strings.  You should change your lists into dictionaries and then use the `class` variables as keys.

Comment: @jk622 could you tell me more about how to do that? I've never worked with dictionaries before. Do you mean that I should make a single dictionary called subjects for example, and then have math, english and so on as keys and the students' names as values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a python dictionary, here's an example

```
classes = {}

classes['english'] = ['eve','beatrice','tim','tom']
classes['math'] = ['tim','tom','mary','fiona']
classes['spanish'] = ['tim','mary','jürgen','mike']
classes['geography'] = ['farquard','fiona','shrek','donkey']

class1,class2 = input('what classes do you want to work with? ').split(',')

class1_clean = []
for name in classes[class1]:
    if name in classes[class2]:
        continue
    class1_clean.append(name)
print(class1_clean)

class2_clean = []
for name in classes[class2]:
    if name in classes[class1]:
        continue
    class2_clean.append(name)
print(class2_clean)
```

Comment: @C.Donau I had a bug in my code which is now fixed fyi